# What does grailsApplication.config.XYZ return if XYZ is not defined?

Tags: grails

Grails 2.4.x here. I am pouring through the code of a quasi-legacy Grails app, and see this little gem:

```
public static boolean isFizz() {
    def isEnabled = isFizz
    if (isEnabled != true && isEnabled != false) {
        // Config is missing, so default to true
        return true            
    }

    isEnabled
}
```

Really? Shouldn't this just be:

```
public static boolean isFizz() {
    def isEnabled = isFizz
    if (isEnabled == null) {
        // Config is missing, so default to true
        return true            
    }

    isEnabled
}
```

What does `grailsApplication.config.XYZ` return if `XYZ` is not defined inside `Config.groovy`? Null? Something else?!?

Comment: As I remember empty map will be returned. You can test it with println

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user3718614 is correct. The result is an empty `Map` -> [:]

Due to [Groovy Truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth), an empty `Map` evaluates to false.